# DAX Create a measure which references the previously calculated value of itself (previous period)

Tags: excel, mdx, powerbi, powerpivot, dax

I would like to create a measure in PowerPivot which references the previously calculated value of itself in the previous iteration.

For example: *[Planned Backlog] n = [Planned OIT] **period n** + (Planned Backlog **period n-1** - Planned Revenue **period n-1**)

So technically it is referencing the previously calculated value along the period dimension.

It is very easy in excel by referencing a previously calculated cell however in a calculated measure it is tricky. [I attached the picture to illustrate how I would do it in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDGRH.png)

I want to do this with a measure because I want to calculate this dynamically in all the aggregation levels. Do you have an idea how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you have to use a mixture of EARLIER and Table iterators like SUMX, maybe this can be of some help https://docs.com/minceddata/3687/dax-using-table-iterators-to-calculate-a-future?c=B13yYP

Comment: Hi @TomMartens,

Sorry for the long delay but I needed to dive into your suggestion. The article and the solution is brilliant! However, I was not able to write the formula for my problem. May I request a little help on how it should be applied in this case? 

I tried it in the sample file under the link in the expression “PlannedBacklog” would you please have a look at it and advise?

https://1drv.ms/f/s!Av6Q0A56ogeghPFdp3UDlgMHgc1S-Q

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of recursive calculation is not possible using dax right now